# Formal proof that two Eigenvalues have to be equal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}(\mathbb{F})$ and $v_1,v_2$ be eigenvectors of $A$ for the eigenvalues $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda _2$. Assume that $v_1+v_2$ is also an eigenvector. Show that $\lambda _1=\lambda _2$.

Assume there are $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda$.

$\lambda _1$ has eigenvector $v_1$.

$\lambda _2$ has eigenvector $v_2$.

...

$\lambda _n$ has eigenvector $v_n$.

Let $\lambda _3$ be the eigenvalue to $v_3=v_1+v_2$.

The eigenvectors build a base and are therefore linearly independent.

But:

$$\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$$
$$\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3\cdot(v_1+v_2)+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$$

With $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ and $\alpha_3=-1$ and $\alpha_i=0$,$i\in\mathbb{N_{>2}}$

Therefore the eigenvectors aren't linearly independent.

If the eigenvector $v_1+v_2$ belongs to eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$
The eigenspace would look (somewhat) like this: $E_A(\lambda_1)=(r\cdot v_1+n\cdot(v_1+v_2),r,n\in \mathbb{R})$
or $E_A(\lambda_2)=(r\cdot v_2+n\cdot(v_1+v_2),r,n\in \mathbb{R})$

With algeabric multiplicity of 1 but geometric mulitplicity of 2 this would be wrong. Therefore the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$ has to be 2. If $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ the eigenvectors can't form a base as there would be one eigenvector too much, therefore $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$

Is this proof correct or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: You went wrong. You have no way of knowing that there is a basis of eigenvectors. Perhaps you’re making this too complicated.

Comment: Hint: first prove that if the eigenvalues are distinct, then the eigenvectors are linearly independent

Comment: @TedShifrin oops you are absolutely right I memorized that one wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.

Then the $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is  linearly independent.

Assume $v_1+v_2$ is an eigen vector  corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda$.

Then $A(v_1+v_2) =\lambda(v_1+v_2)$

Implies $ Av_1+Av_2=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2$

i.e $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2$

Implies $(\lambda_1-\lambda) v_1+(\lambda_2-\lambda) v_2=0$

Now by linear independence of $\{v_1, v_2\}$ , we have $\lambda_1=\lambda=\lambda_2$

which contradict our assumption that $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$Av_1=\lambda_1v_1$$
$$Av_2=\lambda_2v_2$$

Sum them up
$$Av_1+Av_2=A(v_1+v_2)=\lambda(v_1+v_2)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2$$
$$(\lambda-\lambda_2)v_2=(\lambda_1-\lambda)v_1$$

Can you finish?

Comment: If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent your last line says $(\lambda-\lambda_2)=(\lambda_1-\lambda)c$ for some $c\in F$, and then...? At the very least it seems like you need to comment on this or else the hint might be misleading.

Comment: @Arnaldo that was really helpful, thank you!

Comment: @rschwieb, I do not think it is misleading in any way. It is a hint and my calculations work in every situation. It is part of the PO's job to make further considerations and finish the solution.

Comment: @Arnaldo I think your final hint is a dead-end for the case when they are linearly dependent, but maybe you can tell me how you think it goes from that point. Regardless if someone like myself can't see it right away then I think it's worth expanding the hint slightly.